# How to using jQuery to get current date on textbox

Tags: jquery, datepicker

This is my jQuery function but I'm not able to pass the current date and paste it into my textbox, it only able to select the date when doing onClick.

What is need is I would like to select the current date and paste it into my textbox.

```
    gebo_datepicker = {
    init: function() {
        $('#dp1').datepicker();
        $('#dp2').datepicker();

        $('#dp_start').datepicker({format: "mm/dd/yyyy"}).on('changeDate', function(ev){
            var dateText = $(this).data('date');

            var endDateTextBox = $('#dp_end input');
            if (endDateTextBox.val() != '') {
                var testStartDate = new Date(dateText);
                var testEndDate = new Date(endDateTextBox.val());
                if (testStartDate > testEndDate) {
                    endDateTextBox.val(dateText);
                }
            }
            else {
                endDateTextBox.val(dateText);
            };
            $('#dp_end').datepicker('setStartDate', dateText);
            $('#dp_start').datepicker('hide');
        });
        $('#dp_end').datepicker({format: "mm/dd/yyyy"}).on('changeDate', function(ev){
            var dateText = $(this).data('date');
            var startDateTextBox = $('#dp_start input');
            if (startDateTextBox.val() != '') {
                var testStartDate = new Date(startDateTextBox.val());
                var testEndDate = new Date(dateText);
                if (testStartDate > testEndDate) {
                    startDateTextBox.val(dateText);
                }
            }
            else {
                startDateTextBox.val(dateText);
            };
            $('#dp_start').datepicker('setEndDate', dateText);
            $('#dp_end').datepicker('hide');
        });
        $('#dp_modal').datepicker();
    }
};
```

And this is my textbox

```
<div class="input-append date" id="dp_start">
<input class="span9" type="text" readonly="readonly" placeholder="Date Start" /><span class="add-on"><i class="splashy-calendar_day_up"></i></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the current date by

```
var d = new Date();
var month = d.getMonth()+1;
var day = d.getDate();
var output = d.getFullYear() + '/' +
(month<10 ? '0' : '') + month + '/' +
(day<10 ? '0' : '') + day;
```

Then you can assign this value on textbox

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('#dp_start').val($.datepicker.formatDate( "mm/dd/yy", new Date()))
```

Your date format `"mm/dd/yyyy"` is not correct, it should be `"mm/dd/yy"`

Ex:

```
gebo_datepicker = {
    init: function() {
        $('#dp1').datepicker();
        $('#dp2').datepicker();

        //set the current date for dp_start
        $('#dp_start').val($.datepicker.formatDate( "mm/dd/yy", new Date()))
        $('#dp_start').datepicker({format: "mm/dd/yyyy"}).on('changeDate', function(ev){
            var dateText = $(this).data('date');

            var endDateTextBox = $('#dp_end input');
            if (endDateTextBox.val() != '') {
                var testStartDate = new Date(dateText);
                var testEndDate = new Date(endDateTextBox.val());
                if (testStartDate > testEndDate) {
                    endDateTextBox.val(dateText);
                }
            }
            else {
                endDateTextBox.val(dateText);
            };
            $('#dp_end').datepicker('setStartDate', dateText);
            $('#dp_start').datepicker('hide');
        });
        $('#dp_end').datepicker({format: "mm/dd/yyyy"}).on('changeDate', function(ev){
            var dateText = $(this).data('date');
            var startDateTextBox = $('#dp_start input');
            if (startDateTextBox.val() != '') {
                var testStartDate = new Date(startDateTextBox.val());
                var testEndDate = new Date(dateText);
                if (testStartDate > testEndDate) {
                    startDateTextBox.val(dateText);
                }
            }
            else {
                startDateTextBox.val(dateText);
            };
            $('#dp_start').datepicker('setEndDate', dateText);
            $('#dp_end').datepicker('hide');
        });
        $('#dp_modal').datepicker();
    }
};
```

Comment: I'm still unable to get the current date to my textbox. even I have change the date format to "mm/dd/yy"

Comment: Not really sure how to include all the js file but this is my demo http://jsfiddle.net/9xvkj/

Answer (score 0):

For example

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="stDate"/>
```

JS

```
$(function(){
$("#stDate").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy', 
                          changeMonth: true,
                          changeYear: true,
                          yearRange: '-70:+10',
                          constrainInput: false,
                          duration: '',
                          gotoCurrent: true}).datepicker('setDate',"0");
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tkV43/)

Comment: I try the same code as you provide but I still unable to get the current date.

Comment: Can you paste your update code or create jsfiddler for finding the error?

Comment: I have corrected your error. Please check http://jsfiddle.net/amitagrawal/wLLgV/1/

Comment: I have update with another version which it doesn't work and the method you state above I try before it not working for me as well. http://jsfiddle.net/wLLgV/2/